# partial differential equation by Lagrange's method given different solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let
$$z= ax^2 + by^2 …\tag{1}$$

Let $\displaystyle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= 2ax$ and let $p = 2ax$ or $a\displaystyle = \frac p{2x}$

Similarly we get $\displaystyle b= \frac q{2y}$

If we plug in $(1),$ we get, $2z = px + qy$

Now, I solved $(2)$ by Lagrange’s method, in order to get $(1).$ But I didn’t get.

I compared the equation $(2)$  with $Pp+Qq = R$, then $P = x , Q = y$ and $R = 2z$

Now by rule, $dx/P = dy/Q= dz/R$

i.e., $dx/x = dy/y = dz/2z$

Take $dx/x = dy/y$

By solving, I got,$lnx = lny + ln C_1$ or $x/y= c_1$

Similarly $dy/y = dz/2z$ gives us, $2lny = lnz + lnc_2$ or $y^2/z$ = $c_2$

Now by lagrange’s method, solution must be $F(c_1, c_2) =0$

But I got, $F(x/y,y^2/z) = 0$...(3)

When I solve (2), I should get (1). But I got (3). How (1) and (3) are equal? Please explain.

Comment: Instead of using $D$ why don't you use $\partial$ `\partial` instead? 
Fractions can be formatted as $\frac{1}{2}$ `\frac{1}{2}` and $\ln$ as `\ln`.

Comment: alizter! I am very new to typing and now I am learning along with math. Please answer my question.